# Instagram API retorna os dados no network mas não retorna no callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, xmlhttprequest, instagram-api

Estou com um problema estranho e ele é exatamente assim:

Estou consumindo a API do instagram e acontece esta acontecendo a seguinte coisa:

- O retorno e exibido a aba network do devtools, porém no callback da requisição, seja ela feita com XMLHttpRequest, fetch, jQuery.get, etc.. não é mostrado absolutamente nada.
- Na fetch api é mostrado o seguinte erro: TypeError: Failed to fetch

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como solucionar este problema onde, o retorno existe mas não consigo captura-lo no callback da requisição?**

Código que executa a chamada na api do instagram:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque o código js onde você executa a chamada na api.

Comment: Atualizei com o código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, a resposta para este problema é a seguinte:

Se você não consegue recuperar os dados na resposta da sua requisição, tente o seguinte code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: querystring, 
    success: function(data) {
        resolve(data)
    }
});
```

O segreno nessa jogava foi o dataType: 'jsonp'

Abraço